# Show that $\mathbb{Z}$ with the Furstenberg's topology is compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, arithmetic-progressions

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}, b \neq 0$ and $S(a,b):= \{a + nb \in \mathbb{Z}: n\in \mathbb{Z} \} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$. We define the Furstenberg's topology as following:
\begin{align*}
W \subseteq \mathbb{Z} \, \, \, \text{open iff} \, \, \, W = \emptyset \, \, \text{or} \, \, \forall \, a\in W \, \, \exists \, b \neq 0 \, \text{such that} \, \, S(a,b) \subseteq W
\end{align*}
I have to show that $\mathbb{Z}$ with this topology is not compact.

I showed that is not connected but I can't see how to do with the compactness.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This topology should not be credited to Furstenberg. It is the pro-goup topology on $\mathbb{Z}$, a much older definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider these subsets of $\mathbb Z$:

- the odd numbers (numbers of the form $2a+1$);
- the multiples of $3$ (numbers of the form $3a$);
- even numbers which are not multiples of $4$ (numbers of the form $4a+2$);
- multiples of $4$ which are not multiples of $8$ (numbers of the form $8a+4$)

and so on. They form an open cover of $\mathbb Z$, but this open cover has no finite subcover. In fact, no finite number of elements of this open cover contain every power of $2$.

Comment: How about the 0? Is possible that is not contained in no one of these three sets?

Comment: @userr777 I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is correct now.